# TypeError at / Field 'id' expected a number but got <username>

Tags: python, django, forms, typeerror

returns username instead of user.id,i'm try to getting user.id in user_id field but getting username, the user-id field registerd as forignkey fiels of user,so it returns number only
views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cus = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        print(cus)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            task = request.POST['task']
            priority = request.POST['priority']
            date = request.POST['date']
            time = request.POST['time']

            add_task = AddTodo(task=task, priority=priority, date=date, time=time, user_id=cus)
            add_task.save()

            if add_task is not None:
                print("task added suuccesfuly", task)
            else:
                print("task not added", task)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

models.py

```
class AddTodo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

exception:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: captainamerica123>.
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a minimal working example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You passed user object to `user_id` when you create `AddToDo` object.
If you want to create with `user_id`, you have to pass user id not user object.
Of course you can create with user object.
So, you can update code as following

```
add_task = AddTodo(task=task, priority=priority, date=date, time=time, user_id=cus.id)
```

or

```
add_task = AddTodo(task=task, priority=priority, date=date, time=time, user=cus)
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cus = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        print(cus)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            task = request.POST['task']
            priority = request.POST['priority']
            date = request.POST['date']
            time = request.POST['time']

            add_task = AddTodo(task=task, priority=priority, date=date, time=time, user_id=cus.id)
            add_task.save()

            if add_task is not None:
                print("task added suuccesfuly", task)
            else:
                print("task not added", task)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```